# Título de libro separado con "o" para hacerlo más atrayente

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, literatura

He notado que varios títulos de libros o titulares de artículos tienen una estructura algo particular. Básicamente se trata de tener dos ideas, que podrían funcionar cada una como un título por sí mismo, pero que se unen con "o" para generar una especie de similitud que imagino puede hacer ver el título algo atrayente y original.

Estos son algunos ejemplos:

- [Experiencias memorables o cómo hacer que su marca no caiga en el olvido](https://www.marketingdirecto.com/marketing-general/tendencias/experiencias-memorables-o-como-hacer-que-marca-no-caiga-olvido)
- [La discreción o el arte de desaparecer](https://www.traficantes.net/libros/la-discreci%C3%B3n-o-el-arte-de-desaparecer)
- [Ciberstalking o cómo hacer la vida imposible a otro](https://www.efe.com/efe/espana/sociedad/ciberstalking-o-como-hacer-la-vida-imposible-a-otro/10004-3285980)
- [Jerry Seinfeld o el arte de forrarse tirado a la bartola](https://www.elconfidencial.com/cultura/series/2017-09-20/jerry-seinfeld-netflix_1446224/)
- [Resiliencia o el arte de “rebotar”](http://www.xlsemanal.com/firmas/20110911/magazine-firmas-pequenas-infamias-303.html)
- [Estrategia competitiva o el arte de la no guerra](http://smarterworkspaces.kyocera.es/blog/estrategia-competitiva-o-el-arte-de-la-no-guerra/)

¿Existe algún término para designar esta forma de crear títulos? ¿Se trata de una figura literaria o simplemente es un "truco" publicitario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se llama un **subtítulo**, tal y como lo recoge el DLE:

> **1.** *m.* Título secundario que se pone a veces después del título principal.

Es algo bastante típico y tiene mucha historia en la literatura, tanto en castellano como en otros idiomas.  Usando la conjunción *o* tiene menos historia en castellano, siendo más popular sobre todo en el inglés.  Hoy es más común en casi todos los casos emplear algún tipo de puntuación, con los dos puntos la opción plenamente más preferida.

Comment: No puedo poner comentarios, pero creo que la respuesta de **guifa** no es del todo correcta. En su propia definición indica que el subtitulo "se pone a veces después del titulo principal", mientras que en los ejemplos planteados por **Mauricio Martinez** la parte después de la "o" forma parte del titulo y no es un "título secundario".

Comment: Ese es un punto muy interesante. Voy a ver si encuentro un ejemplo como los que listé en la pregunta y que además tenga, en una línea aparte, un subtítulo como lo que uno conoce más comúnmente. Ese sería un contraejemplo. Por ahora, esperar a ver si alguien tiene otra idea.

Comment: Lo que indica el OP forma parte del título, no es un subtitulo. Ejemplo: Titulo: "**Angelina o el honor de un brigadier**" - subtítulo: "**Un drama en 1880**" de Jardiel Poncela (1934).

Comment: @moo lo que describes se llama un *ladillo*.

Comment: No conocía la palabra *ladillo*, pero no veo claro que sea como indicas: según el DLE, ladillo es 2. m. Impr. Composición breve que suele colocarse en el margen de la plana, generalmente para indicar el contenido del texto. La descripción de éstos en http://www.aulafacil.com/cursos/l9479/arte-humanidades/periodismo/periodismo-estilo-informativo/los-ladillos-mas-sobre-ladillos tampoco parece corresponder. ¿Podrías ampliar por qué es un ladillo o sería ya off-topic? Gracias

Comment: guifa: te habrán aparecido dos comentarios nuevos (los dos primeros). Se trata de una respuesta convertida a comentario.

Answer (score 3):

Este tipo de títulos se llaman "[**titulos dobles**](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ortotipograf%C3%ADa_de_t%C3%ADtulos_de_publicaciones#T.C3.ADtulos_dobles)" y lo correcto es que la "segunda parte" se escriba también con mayúscula:

> **2.2 Títulos dobles**
>   Algunos títulos constan de **dos partes unidas por la conjunción *o***, a modo de título doble, donde el segundo elemento suele servir de explicación. La segunda parte también empieza con mayúscula y la conjunción *o* conserva la cursiva:
>     *Bearn o La casa de muñecas*
>     *Pamela o La virtud recompensada*

Los ejemplos que comentas deberían estar por tanto escritos así:

*Experiencias memorables o Cómo hacer que su marca no caiga en el olvido

La discreción o El arte de desaparecer

Ciberstalking o Cómo hacer la vida imposible a otro

Jerry Seinfeld o El arte de forrarse tirado a la bartola

Resiliencia o El arte de “rebotar”

Estrategia competitiva o El arte de la no guerra*

Esto **no es lo mismo que un subtítulo**, concepto que se refiere a un [título secundario](http://recursos.cnice.mec.es/fp/artes/ut.php?familia_id=5&ciclo_id=1&modulo_id=1&unidad_id=130&menu_id=1554&pagina=&pagestoyen=12&submenu_id=3696&ncab=10&contadort=12), que complementa al principal y se escribe habitualmente bajo este. Nótese que el subtítulo se define como un título en sí mismo, no como parte de uno.

La diferencia entre título doble y subtítulo es que el título doble es un único título formado por dos frases u oraciones, mientras que el subtítulo es un título separado que complementa al título principal.